# Doing things with objects as if they were parents

Tags: c#, inheritance

The following code give me an error saying that there are invalid arguments in my call of `doStuffToLines(segments)`

Shouldn't I be able to do this since I have my `DimensionLineSegment` inherits from  Lines?

```
    private void doStuff()
    {
        List<DimensionLineSegment> segments = new List<DimensionLineSegment>();

        doStuffToLines(segments);

    }

    private void doStuffToLines(List<Line> lines)
    {

    }
```

Comment: @OP : Does DimensionLineSegment inherits from Line ? Is this what you are saying ?

Comment: yes it does inherit from line

Comment: List, which implements IList<T> is not covariant.

Comment: You can't do this since `List<T>` is invariant. You could change the type of `lines` in `doStuffToLines` to `IEnumerable<Line>` and it might compile depending on how you're using `lines` in that function.

Comment: Read more about covariance here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a concrete type to the method because List is not covariant.

You can try something like this:

```
public void doStuffToLines<T>(IList<T> lines) where T : Line
{
  //do some thing           
}
```

By specifying a generic constraint, you can limit the generic type passed to a object of type Line or it's derived descendants.

One thing to note, is if you're using .NET 4.0, you could potentially change your method from accepting List to IEnumerable because the T generic parameter is covariant.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<T>` would work from .NET ≥ 2.0 onwards; from .NET ≥ 4.5 onwards you could also use `IReadOnlyList<T>`, which is also covariant.